# Using MySQLi PHP code to create and manage partitioned tables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, partitioning

I want to be able to create partitioned tables using PHP code rather than manually run the query in phpMyAdmin, can this be done?

I am using MySQLi where I can because this is safer than MySQL.

Currently at the moment a typical table of mine is created like so....

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `fred` (
`id` INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`data1` VARCHAR(256),
`data2` VARCHAR(256),
`data3` VARCHAR(256),
`data4` VARCHAR(256)
) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci"; 

// Performs the $sql query on the server to create the table
if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo 'Table Fred created successfully';
}
else {
  echo 'Error: '. $mysqli->error;
}
```

How do I write this so it's partitioned?

Comment: First time I hear about partition in mysql :) take a look [this](http://chrisjohnson.blogsite.org/programatically-building-mysql-partitioned-tables/)

Comment: Yes I came across that article in my searches too, maybe I am reading that code wrong but as best as I can tell that just spits out the SQL text to use when manually creating partitioned tables in MySQL. What I am looking for, if it exists or is possible, is PHP script that actually creates a table in MySQL that is partitioned without me having to manually copy and paste something in the command line in myphpadmin. I can create a non partitioned table in PHP that will automatically do it for me, surely there is a way to automate this with a partitioned table in PHP too?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `invoice_detail2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `office_code` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `order_type` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'purchase order, sale order, transfer in, transfer out, debit note, credit note',
  `in_out_flag` int(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '1=in, 2=out',
  `order_no` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `order_date` date NOT NULL,
  `item_no` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `item_qty` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `item_unit` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `unit_price_loc` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `unit_price_fc` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `curr_code` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `exch_rate` int(7) NOT NULL,
  `total_price_loc` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
  `total_price_fc` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
  `include` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `includ_vat_tax` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `bar_code` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `item_origin` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `item_waranty` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `warranty_type` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `agaunest_indent_no` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `order_statud` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status_date` date NOT NULL,
  `status_ref` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ss_creator` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ss_created_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ss_modifier` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ss_modofier_on` date NOT NULL
)PARTITION BY RANGE (month(order_date)) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (1),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (3),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (4),
    PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (5),
     PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (6),
    PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN (7),
    PARTITION p7 VALUES LESS THAN (8),
    PARTITION p8 VALUES LESS THAN (9),
    PARTITION p9 VALUES LESS THAN (10),
     PARTITION p10 VALUES LESS THAN (11),
    PARTITION p11 VALUES LESS THAN (12)
);
```